# How to include external entities on persistence.xml file

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I need to include external entity class files on my persistence.xml file, how can I do it?

I have multiple Eclipse projects that are my system's modules and I have a test in which I need to use a persistence unit that's inside another project, so, how can I make my code "aware" of other entities? How can I list them on my persistence.xml file.

Also, one more detail:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [delete from JpaProfile]. 
[12, 22] The abstract schema type 'JpaProfile' is unknown.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1605)
```

This is the error which shows up on my Failure trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly state what classes to use using the `<class>` tag.

```
<class>com.test.jpa.entity.Test</class>
```

So as long as that class is on the class path, you should be good to go.